# How to create jQuery table and Dynamically add & remove table rows using jQuery in asp.net c#

Tags: jquery

I have zero knowledge in js and jQuery scripting language and I'm new in the programming(coding) language.

I should create jQuery table but don't know how to start. How to create the jQuery table? A code example will give me the best understanding

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: Hi Naveen sir, thanks for your comment actually I didn't start because I don't know how to start and getting confusion would you help me how to start and also can you provide any reference links that would be help me a lot .